# Set up datasource in ColdFusion 9 for MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion-9

I am trying to set up a datasource to my database that is hosted by my hosting company.  I am creating the datasource using ColdFusion Administrator 9.  I called my hosting company and received all the necessary information to get things going.  After inputting the necessary information I get a connection failure, something to the effect that it has timed out.  I noticed that when the administrator page came up to create the datasource, the default port number was 1433.  Is this common? I feel all the necessary information I inputted was correct( username, password, databasename, server, etc;). Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Here is the error: Connection verification failed for data source: cfhalloween
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket. Unknown host: s
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket. Unknown host: s

Answer (score 7):

1433 is the port commonly used by SQL Server. That's likely correct.

> Error establishing socket. Unknown host: s

This suggests you have the value `s` listed for `server`. Instead, this should be the hostname or IP address of the SQL Server as seen from the server running CF.

Comment: and don't forget to enable TCP/IP access from MS SQL, and make sure it is port 1433, not "dynamic"

Comment: @Henry How do I determine the server name if I have MS SQL Server 2014 installed locally on my machine and I am not using any IP. I tried using `MSSQLSERVER` but it gave me the same error as above.

Comment: localhost? 127.0.0.1 ?